# jquery ui datepicker : custom dayname headers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, customization, jquery-ui-datepicker

general information:
I'm using the datpicker to set opening hours for stores.. for an entire year.
For this I have buttons to select all mondays etc of the entire year and then i have other buttons that add the classes. 
for instance you click "monday", which selects all mondays of the year in the calendar. 
then you click the 'class' button and all mondays get the openening hours '9:00-17:00'.

I do this by saving an array of 366 days with the class info for each day. So every selection of one or more day is simply converted to a day of the year and that index of the array is updated.

this works nicely but now i want to achieve the same effect on a week basis. so i did the following:

i'm trying to achieve custom daynames, turning them into links to select for instance all mondays of that month.
what i got so far:

```
//javascript
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
...
    beforeShowDay: setHollidays,
    dayNamesMin: ['<a class="weekSelector" href="7">Zo</a>', 
                  '<a class="weekSelector" href="1">Ma</a>', 
                  '<a class="weekSelector" href="2">Di</a>', 
                  '<a class="weekSelector" href="3">Wo</a>', 
                  '<a class="weekSelector" href="4">Do</a>', 
                  '<a class="weekSelector" href="5">Vr</a>', 
                  '<a class="weekSelector" href="6">Za</a>'],
    monthNames: ['January<span class="invisible">0</span>',
  'February<input type="hidden" value="1" class="invisible"/>',
  'March<input type="hidden" value="2" class="invisible"/>', 
  'April<input type="hidden" value="3" class="invisible"/>',
  'May<input type="hidden" value="4" class="invisible"/>', 
  'June<input type="hidden" value="5" class="invisible"/>',
  'July<input type="hidden" value="6" class="invisible"/>',
  'August<input type="hidden" value="7" class="invisible"/>',
  'September<input type="hidden" value="8" class="invisible"/>',
  'October<input type="hidden" value="9" class="invisible"/>',
  'November<input type="hidden" value="10" class="invisible"/>', 
  'December<input type="hidden" value="11" class="invisible"/>'],
...
});

//selects all days of the month (for one month) that are a given week days. for example: all mondays
$("a.weekSelector").click(function () {
    selDay = $(this).attr("href"); // get the day index
    markerType = 'month'; //use in beforeShowday function to select the days
```

// added code 
         var container = $(this).parent('.ui-datepicker-group');
    alert($(container).find('.invisible').val());
  // end of added code
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("refresh");
        resetMultiSelect(); //reset variables used for the selection
        return false;
    });

```
//setHollidays adds the correct classes the the days.
```

this works as well, but if the days always get selected in the first month (ie january).
Because i don't have acces to the month. so when i select the header 'monday' for the month 'march' ,all mondays for january are selected.

so finally here's my question: how can i get the month (or first date in the month) in the $("a.weekSelector").click function?

edit: when it's finished it will be turned into a drupal module and probably a jquery plugin.

Comment: Ok i'm one step further. I added hidden input fields behind the monthNames to store the month id/value.  Now I can look that field up in my $("a.weekSelector").click function. the problem i'm having now is that the alert shows null instead of the month value. I tried with both a span and a hidden input... any ideas why this doesn't work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my 'dirty' way to fix it (in the click function):

```
var el = $(this);
var offset = el.offset();
var elTop = offset.top;
var elLeft = offset.left;

var arr = $("a.weekSelector[href='"+selDay+"']");   
$.each(arr, function(i, val) {
 var curTop = $(val).offset().top;
 var curLeft = $(val).offset().left;
 if((elTop == curTop) && (elLeft == curLeft))
{
selmonth = $(".invisible:eq("+i+")").val();
 }
});
```

what this basically does is retrieve all the weekselectors with the same href as the one clicked (for example all the 'monday' links), then compare there offset to the offset of the clicked element.
then I used the id I get from that, to search for the hidden field.

I tried searching through the DOM for the hidden field but it always seemed to return undefined.